# How to calculate small peak in python with CSV

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2 column txt file which I want to know the value of the small bump around 0.8V for (see picture). What is the best way to calculate this. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxYx3.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
data = np.genfromtxt("220525_01-O2-LSV-LMOink-1600rpm-rep1.txt", delimiter=";", names=["x", "y"])
data_2 = np.genfromtxt("220525_01-O2-LSV-LMOink-1600rpm-rep2.txt", delimiter=";", names=["x", "y"])
plt.plot(data['x'], data['y'], label='ORR polarization repetition 1')
plt.plot(data_2['x'], data_2['y'], label='ORR polarization repetition 2')

plt.title('LSV LMO-ink')
plt.xlabel('Potential Applied ($V$)')
plt.ylabel('Current ($A$)')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('ORR.png', dpi=100)
plt.show()
```

I tried it with find_peak. But did not succeed.

Comment: Maybe make a fit with a model function and find the peak in the residual?

Comment: @mkrieger1 is it maybe possible with taking a derivative?